# How server should respond to the CORS request in case if origin is not in the allowed origins list?

Tags: javascript, web, cors

In my case client requests not simple html page or JavaScript from server, but it calls some server-side methods.
These method will perform some activity on server - print documents, store to db, etc.
Server should perform these actions only if the origin from request is in the list of allowed origins.
Otherwise server should response to client that origin is not in the allowed origins list.
How to do it correctly?
Set response header Access-Control-Allow-Origin to 'null'? Or do not set Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response at all?
What response code should be set in this case? 200, 401, ...?

Answer (score 1):

[Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) is an "opt-in", it means you only put CORS headers in your responses if you are willing to enable it. Browsers will make it a little harder for some attacks if you do not set CORS headers, but you still need to protect your backend server against [Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)](http://marc.info/?l=bugtraq&m=99263135911884&w=2).

You can protect yourself by checking `Referer` and `Origin` of the request, and denying the request, returning a `Forbidden` status, for example. The thing is: the browser will look at CORS headers **after** issuing the request to your site, so if you happen to modify any stuff, it will happen even if you tell the browser that its origin is not allowed.

The browser may issue an `OPTIONS` request before sending other dangerous verbs (`DELETE`, `PUT`, `POST`), but then you are betting on the browser doing the right thing. Also, anyone can send any HTTP request to your webserver with simple tools like [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/).

Protect your backend server with other things, like only issuing commands if the request has an Access Token that is unguessable by third parties. If you are not planning in sharing your services with other domains, deny any request that contains CORS headers before processing them.